# AppStore MetaData Rejection

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, metadata, appstore-approval

AppStore has rejected the metadata of my game. The reason is :

```
3.8: Developers are responsible for assigning appropriate ratings to their apps. Inappropriate ratings may be changed/deleted by Apple
3.8
```

We found that the rating you selected for your app was not consistent with the content of your app, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.

Since your app includes content or features that pertain to guns or gun-related activities, your ratings must reflect a "`Frequent/Intense`" setting for "`Realistic Violence`" in iTunes Connect.

You can revise your ratings in iTunes Connect, Manage Your Applications. View the details of the appropriate app, then edit the Version Information to access the Ratings tab and select the settings.If your iTunes Connect Application State is Rejected, a new binary will be required. Make the desired metadata changes when you upload the new binary.

If your iTunes Connect Application State is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT require a new binary. In iTunes Connect > Manage Your Applications, select your app and click View Details.

- Click Edit in the Metadata section
- Revise the desired metadata values
- Click "Save" at the bottom of the screen
- Once you click Save, you will see the "`Submit New Metadata`" button in the top right. Click "`Submit New Metadata`"

NOTE: Please be sure to make any metadata changes to all App Localizations by clicking the Edit button next to each localization.

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: What do you need help with? Apple's reply tells you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 2):

May be they are complaining about this part:

[image]

For each point judge your app. Hope this helps.. :)